# Control Where Objects Are Distributed on a Curve (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a curve, with monkey heads distributed on them. I want to control where the monkeys are placed along the curve. Specifically, I want the monkey heads to stop being distributed before they reach the top of the curve. But right now, they are randomly placed all over the curve. Is there any way to control that with geometry nodes? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

If your definition of the *top* of the curve is known from the curve linear abscissa, you can use *Trim Curve* nodes to split it in two, only the *bottom* part being seeded with instances, like that:
[image: Trim curve graph]

If your definition of the *top* of the curve is known from 3D world coordinates, you can use the *Selection* socket of the *Instance on Points* node linked to a selection mask based on *Position*, like this:
[image: Selection graph]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!